# Single word for "separated for a while with the expectation to be reunited"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a story in first person view. In that story the main character is writing about how he is now separated from a once close friend. In telling the story, I want the main character to subtly express how he really want to reunite with the friend when he say the word that is supposed to mean "separated". So what I'm looking for is a word that also carries the expectation to be reunited in addition to be separated, that can be used to replace the word "separated" in the following sentence:

> This is the story of me being separated.

And as a side note, I actually want to use the word as the title of the story also.

Comment: Perhaps *au revoir-ed*?

Comment: Ah, that comes from the exact definition of *au revoir*, doesn't it? But it's more to "goodbye" than "separated", and I guess I'm looking for a more formal word. It's creative though! =) I added a more concrete sample sentence where the word will be used.

Comment: There is "disunited", which at least contains the word "united" for that association. But I think that would be better for a "How we became disunited" construction.

Comment: Why not move this from an adjective describing the person (I am not sure one exists with the nuances you want) to one describing something else. For example, "This is the story of our time apart." You could title it Apart. It would be very odd to refer to "time apart" for two people who never reunited.

Comment: @KateGregory: Apart looks great actually. I will consider that. Thanks. =)

Comment: @ermanen: it doesn't have to, but I prefer to. =D

Comment: @nxx: "disunited" sounds more like towards divisions in a group of people, not just among two people (or parties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you may need is 'parted'. When you 'part' from someone it does not sound as permanent as 'separate' does.

If you want something less strong than 'part', consider 'withdraw'.

I do not think there is a word which means to part with the intention of reuniting. To achieve that you would have to say something like 'temporary separation', or 'short-term parting' etc.

Comment: Parted actually sounds good, as so with "withdraw". I like the emotional impression with the word "parted" (or is it only me?). Thank you for your suggestions on the phrases, I'll consider those if I can't get the word I want. =)

Answer (score 3):

Not a single word, but the phrase **held in [abeyance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abeyance)** has some of the characteristics you are seeking

> (usually preceded by in or into) a state of being suspended or put aside temporarily

The verb **[suspended](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspend)** also convey much of what you seek, although not limite to being separated

> to force (someone) to leave a job, position, or place for a usually short period of time as a form of punishment

Comment: The definition of suspended fits quite nicely to what I'm looking for, but to use "suspended" I guess I need to change the sentence a bit, as it doesn't really focus on the "separated" part if I just use that to directly replace the word "separated". Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: For abeyance, I see that the meaning in law is related to something being in an indeterminate state of ownership, I don't really want that. However, I like the word origin: "a gaping after, a reaching towards". So this could possibly fit my need. I'm not really familiar with the word, but what comes to your mind when you see a story titled "Abeyance"?

Comment: Awaiting what comes next. With eager (and maybe ominous) anticipation.

Comment: Hmm, I prefer a word with more positive anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to contribute a coined word: "Preunited". You're welcome.

Comment: Looks good also, but it puts too much emphasis on the reunion. As I said, the word should primarily mean "separated", and I want it to subtly convey the expectation of the main character to be reunited.

Comment: I actually used this word (actually "Preunion") in another writing (a poem) of mine as the title. So, thank you Spehro! +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

what is wrong with **absence**? 
Perhaps it is a little bit more cryptical but therefore more interesting in my opinion.

Comment: That's actually quite fitting, thank you for your suggestion. But in my story I don't use any word to refer to the other person, while using "absence" requires me to refer to the other person as in "the absence of my friend".

Answer (score 0):

What about **interval**?

The play or film always commences after the interval. Likewise when two friends are separated but are destined to reunite, we could call that period an interval.

= space of time between two events or actions; break, pause, intermission; space between two periods of time; difference in pitch between two musical tones

Comment: Looks good to refer to the time period. But I guess I want the word to refer to the state of being separated, not just the time in which they are separated.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, it seems that the emotions come from the build-up to the reunion. Perhaps that's something to focus on instead of the separation itself?

> I actually want to use the word as the title of the story also.

Perhaps this is something that gives you more literary freedom in discounting the literal meaning of the words? "Made up" words in the sense of not following the dictionary definition could work, such as *unseparation* and its derivatives. This works especially well for a romantic scenario imho, so whoever comes up with *"Undivorced, the"* NYT bestseller should send through royalties.

If this were not about friends but a romantic relationship, you would focus on the repetition of the act with *reunion*, *re-connection* or *remarriage*. You can't quite do that with *befriend* but you could with *reacquainted*, and if you're not writing for twitter the title could grow a bit to *"Befriended, again"*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the main question is on the usage of that word in the main content, not the title, so I do want an existing word. =) And from other parts of the story, indeed I have written it in such a way that conveys the expectation of the main character to be reunited, and now I want to put that expectation a little bit more through the usage of this specific word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You *[take a break](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22taking%20a%20break%22%20relationship%20&gbv=2&oq=%22taking%20a%20break%22%20relationship%20&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0l3j0i22i30l7.414450.448618.0.449849.40.36.4.0.0.4.252.4378.8j25j2.35.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..11.29.3177.7VPsAxkqoBI)* in a relationship.

> *he is **taking a break** from a once-close friend*

Read up on the idea from the various resources the above Google Search brings up. Interesting.

Comment: It's interesting indeed that "taking a break" is highly correlated with "taking a break from someone" in Google. Thanks for the insight, but I guess it's not taking a break, as the separation was not voluntary, as "taking a break" suggests.